# Converting code to use JSON.net instead of System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json

How do I do the equivalent in JSON.net?

```
 public SerializedResults SerializeResults(Type queryType, IEnumerable entities)
      {
          var results = SerializeDynamicType(queryType);

          var objList = AnonymousFns.DeconstructMany(entities, false, queryType).ToList();

          var ms = new MemoryStream();
          var type = objList.GetType();
          var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type);

          using (ms)
          {
              using (GZipStream compress = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.BestCompression))
              {
                  serializer.WriteObject(compress, objList);
              }
          }

          results.ByteArray = ms.ToArray();

          return results;
      }
```

I am confused with this line in particular:
     var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type);

How do you do that in JSON.NET??

THANKS :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the BsonWriter to write to a stream.  I'm not sure it will give you the exact same binary format you had before, but in concept it is the same.

```
  public SerializedResults SerializeResults(Type queryType, IEnumerable entities)
  {
      var results = SerializeDynamicType(queryType);

      var objList = AnonymousFns.DeconstructMany(entities, false, queryType).ToList();

      var ms = new MemoryStream();         

      using (ms)
      {
          using (GZipStream compress = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.BestCompression))
          {
            using( BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(compress))
            {
              JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();                 
              serializer.Serialize(writer, objList);
            }
          }
      }

      results.ByteArray = ms.ToArray();

      return results;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With JSON.NET, you don't need the type when serializing.  I'm assuming that it works out the type you are passing in on its own.

So, you can get rid of this completely:

```
var type = objList.GetType();
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type);
```

And change this:

```
serializer.WriteObject(compress, objList);
```

To:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objList);
```

Here are the JSON.Net [docs](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) for JsonConvert.

Comment: You can pass the json string to the stream, but of course it won't be a streamed operation and instead you'll have the entire json string in memory.  Not a problem unless the object is very large.

Comment: @AaronLS yes that is right.  I decided to focus on the point the OP made about not understanding the type parameter.

Comment: Yeh probably not a big deal either way, since in the end they are doing ToArray, so it all ends up in memory anyways.